# Setting properties from one interface in another with inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript, interface

Is it possible to set the properties of one interface by generating an instance of another from which the first interface inherits?

For example, I have a `user` interface with a function that generates a random instance.

```
import * as Chance from 'chance';

export interface User {
    username: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    gender: string;
    streetAddress: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zipCode: string;
    country: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
}

export function generateRandomUser(): User {
    let randomuser: User;

    randomuser.firstName = Chance.first();
    randomuser.lastName = Chance.last();
    randomuser.username = randomuser.firstName + randomuser.lastName;
    randomuser.password = 'password';

    return randomuser;
}
```

Then I have another interface for a more specific user, let's say it's `ProUser`, which has another generate function

```
import { User, generateRandomUser } from '../user';
import * as Chance from 'chance';

interface ProUser extends User {
    favoriteColor: string;
}

function generateRandomProUser(): ProUser {
    let generalUser = generateRandomUser();
    let randomProUser: ProUser;

    // simple way to set the props from generalUser to randomProUser??

    randomProUser.favoriteColor = Chance.color();

    return randomProUser;
}
```

Is there an easy way to map these properties over? I have other user types that could use this mapping functionality as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
function generateRandomProUser(): ProUser {
    let randomProUser = generateRandomUser() as ProUser;
    randomProUser.favoriteColor = Chance.color();

    return randomProUser;
}
```

Another option is to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
function generateRandomProUser(): ProUser {
    let generalUser = generateRandomUser();
    let randomProUser = Object.assign({}, generalUser) as ProUser;

    randomProUser.favoriteColor = Chance.color();

    return randomProUser;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was something, but wasn't sure where to look. Thanks.